# Laravel 8 page expired 419 on post request when move to new domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I move the project to another domain directory in the same server
i just clear cache, routes, views, config
then update the composer and generate new keys
but it gives me (419 page expired) in any post request
and CSRF token mismatch in Ajax request
domain DNS from cloudflare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution for my problem
the domain value in the config/session.php file is related to the old domain
i change to new domain and this solve the problem